# Is ‘just’ an adjective in ‘just anyone’?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, idiom-meaning, negative-polarity-items

Given this sentence:

> Nina wouldn’t give her phone number to **just anyone**.

I’ve checked several dictionaries (Oxford, Longman, Cambridge, Macmillan)
for the word *just* from the example above. It **looks** like it is an
adjective modifying the pronoun *anyone*.

However, the meanings provided do not fit the above situation.

Finally, I
found that *just anyone* is listed as an idiom in Merriam-Webster
dictionary.  As Merriam-Webster is an American dictionary, is *just anyone*
an idiom in American English only? I can’t find the entry in the four
dictionaries I mentioned.

Comment: _Just anyone_ is a perfectly normal expression to me as a British English speaker.

Comment: The idiom "just anyone" is found in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just%20anyone) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/not-just-anyone). Google is helpful for this kind of thing.

Comment: I find it odd that it's classified as an idiom. To me, it's at best a set phrase, since the meaning can be directly deduced from common definitions of the words themselves - just (simply) anyone (any person).

Comment: Can you add inks and quotes of the definitions that you mention here? Otherwise this is missing a lot of context, especially since the dictionary entries are what you are asking about.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an idiom *per se*, nor is it confined to American English alone. It is a perfectly normal construction used by native speakers worldwide, one that follows naturally once you realize that *just anybody* is a kind of negative.

### Attributive adjectives can only ever *follow* indefinite pronouns, never precede them as with nouns.

The OP is mistaking the part of speech of the modifier *just* here in their sentence:

1. Nina wouldn’t give her phone number to **just anyone.**

Modifiers that ***precede*** indefinite pronouns are
always adverbs, never adjectives. For example:

2. **Absolutely nobody** is allowed behind the curtain.

That’s because pronouns are not quite like nouns when it comes to
adjectives: attributive adjectives that modify an indefinite pronoun can
only ever be placed ***after*** the pronoun they modify, never before it.

These
are grammatical:

3. We need **somebody brave** to save us.
4. **Somebody brave** just volunteered.

But these are not grammatical:

5. We need ❌brave somebody to save us.
6. ❌Brave somebody just volunteered.

This unusual requirement that the attributive adjective must **follow** the
indefinite pronoun is because these are the remnants of copular clauses
that have been whittled down via the process known as [*whiz*-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiz-deletion):

7. We need somebody **[who is]** brave to save us.
8. Somebody **[who is]** brave just volunteered.

The adjective *just* refers to the quality of justice:

9. Any just person would free the falsely condemned prisoner.
10. Any person who was just would free the prisoner.
11. Anybody who was just would free the prisoner.
12. Anybody just would free the prisoner.

But that is **not** at all what is going on here. It does not mean anybody
just; it means anybody whatsoever or anybody at all, which like most modern uses of *any* is a kind of negative.  Those are therefore adverbial
uses.

So this is not an instance of a misplaced adjective *just* but rather
the focusing adverb *just* in one possible location in the sentence.  The
poster’s sentence is exactly equivalent to one with the focusing adverb
*just* moved elsewhere in the sentence:

13. Nina wouldn’t **just** give her phone number to anyone.

With the implication that she wouldn’t just hand out her personal, private
phone number to absolutely any random stranger who asked her for it.

Compare that with the same type of movement you see happening with the
focusing adverb *only* in such sentences as:

14. She didn’t **only** give it to John.
15. She didn’t give it **only** to John.
16. She didn’t give it to **only** John.
17. She didn’t give it to John **only**.

### Negative polarity items

You might notice, by the way, that *absolutely* is [only used like this in negatives](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/absolutely). This is also the case with *just*. The negation of the main verb in *wouldn’t give* is what licenses and indeed requires that it be *just anyone* not *just someone*.

18. Absolutely anybody at all will do.
19. Just anybody at all will do.
20. Absolutely ❌somebody at all will do.
21. Just ❌somebody at all will do.

Comment: I could see someone saying "We need ***a*** brave somebody to save us now."

Comment: Illuminating!  Tiny quibble, I don't think it's always negative.  *Do you mean for this experiment you don't want us to target a certain demographic?  We'll choose just anyone to approach with the questionnaire?*  I think one meaning would involve a random selection, or seemingly random.

Comment: @aparente001 Interrogatives are negative contexts: *Have you ever seen anybody like that?* is fine, but *I have ❌ever seen ❌anybody like that* is ungrammatical. Similarly, *Will you give this to just anyone?* is a negative context.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree on that.  It doesn't seem negative to me.  I see it as meaning "selected at random."

Comment: @Robusto Sure, but as soon as you used an article, you just made that a noun not an indefinite pronoun, the same way you do when you say *An earlier me would have known better*.

Comment: @aparente001 You need to study negative polarity items and negative contexts. Just because something is a negative context does not mean that there's an overt negative. Like interrogatives, superlatives are also negative contexts for the purposes of triggering NPIs: *That's the biggest joke I've ever seen* is grammatical but *That's a joke I've ❌ever seen* is ungrammatical. The superlative is what licenses the NPI; without it, it's wrong.  Hit up John Lawler on this: he's a citable authority on NPIs.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know what was meant by *negative contexts*.  Thank you. / You opened with "is a kind of negative" -- I think you could strengthen the post by editing this to make it more precise,

Comment: It’s relevant that “Nina wouldn’t give her phone number to anyone” has quite a different meaning from “Nina wouldn’t give her phone number to just anyone.” Nina discriminates.

Comment: Hmm. “Absolutely everyone knows that!” / “We sent copies to absolutely everybody”. *Absolutely* only deals with the extremities, i.e. everything or nothing, but the everything group is positive.

Comment: PS the interesting data here seem to show that the *any/some/no* etc series of words are compound determinatives, not pronouns (if you believe that there’s any such distinction to be made). In any case, the “absolutely” is best analysed as modifying a whole NP (because adverbs can modify  NPs, but not nouns. For example “Almost a dollar” versus “ An almost dollar”)

Answer (score 3):

At [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/just) under **ADVERB**...definition **4.1**:

Really; absolutely (used for emphasis)

At [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/just):

Just is a common adverb in English, especially in speaking. It has different meanings.

***Just* meaning ‘simply’ or ‘absolutely’**

We can use *just* meaning ‘simply’ or ‘absolutely’ to add emphasis to a statement:

```
It’s just not right.

Our holiday was just perfect.
```

So '*just anyone*' means '*simply anyone*' or '*absolutely anyone*'.